# Breaking apart a database-heavy application

Tags: database-design, reporting, soa

I'm currently working on a database-heavy, line-of-business Rails application for insurance brokers that is around 90 KLOC - most of it is data manipulation through business transactions, along multiple reports to aggregate all that data.

We are on a very small team, and the code base size and complexity are starting to outgrow our capacity to manage it. Because of that, we are researching ways to tame it, one of which is converting it to a Service-Oriented Architecture - that is, splitting it on several smaller applications.

The problem with that approach is on the reporting side: Our reports usually involve tables that are up to 7 joins away, with the filters acting on multiple tables along the way. If we discard the possibility of services sharing tables (which is stated on multiple articles to be an anti-pattern), would it be possible to join all this data in a way that does not hurt performance much?

So, is a SOA the approach recommended for that kind of problem? Or does it bring more problems than it solves?

While our expertise lies mostly on Ruby (Rails and Sinatra) and Python (Plone and Grok), I would also like to know how the communities around other technologies (.NET, Java) usually handle this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am from a Data Warehouse background, and keep some interest in ruby/rails.
Reading your post, I get a feeling that your reporting architecture might need a redesign, and to be broken away from the base system.

With that segment redesigned, perhaps your original system wouldnt be as big/complex.

In a nutshell, a reporting requirement that goes through 7 levels of join make me feel "awkward", looks like you are trying to use your transactional system for reporting ?

I suggest you move to a different schema/database with pre-calculated aggregates (of course leverage will be dependent upon your business case).  That should help in reducing complexity of base system, as well as allowing you faster and relatively simpler reporting environment.  You might incur some storage cost (for the separate db/schema for the aggs env) but that should be small price to pay for simplicity/design.

hth

Comment: Would that mean using a shared database approach for both services? I can't visualize how the synchronization between two databases would happen... I'm quite a newbie in this area, can you point me to some resources?

Comment: That would having a db1 for transactional purposes, and possibly db2 (or schema2) for reporting purposes.  You would need to build some aggregate generation code for populating db2/schema2 depending upon reporting requirements.

Answer (score 1):

SOA will indeed help you keeping code bases of the respected services smaller and with better separation. It will also simplify your operational databases as the database of each service will be separated.  The down side of course is that it doesn't work well for reporting.

On the other hand, As learn4living noted, you are probably better off with a separate schema for reporting anyway since operational databases are not convenient for reporting and denormalized data is easier to work with.

I call the pattern around this [aggregated reporting](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/aggregated-reporting/) and you can read an article I wrote about it a few years ago, on [bridging the gap between BI and SOA](http://www.infoq.com/articles/BI-and-SOA)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of SOA,Batch Processing and caching will address your concerns to a large extent. You need to identify what processes

1. Should be made for High Availability (**Webservices/Messaging**)
2. Can your users afford to wait for results (**Batching**)
3. Can tolerate the display/consumption of stale data (**Caching**)

It might also be worth your while to invest in a bit of denormalization for long-term benefit.